# Python - TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, class, typeerror

(Using Python 2.7)

Hello,

I've two version of a class PairOfDice.

1.) This one is not working and throws an error.

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

```
import random

class PairOfDice:
    """ Represent the Pair of Dices and have method which tells the total of those roles.
    """
    def roll(self):
        self.total = random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1, 6)

    def total(self):
        return self.total

    def name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

player1 = PairOfDice()
player1.roll()
print player1.total()
```

2) This one is working.

```
import random

class PairOfDice:
    """ Represent the Pair of Dices and have method which tells the  total of those roles.
    """
    def roll(self):
        self.roll1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        self.roll2 = random.randint(1, 6)

    def total(self):
        return self.roll1 + self.roll2

    def name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

player1 = PairOfDice()
player1.roll()
print player1.total()
```

Can please someone explain what's wrong with the first one?

Thanks

Comment: Assigning a value to `self.total` overrides the `self.total` method; you're calling that number in the last line of the first example.  A class instance only has one namespace, including both values and methods.

Comment: Although the error message for the first duplicate does not match, the underlying cause is the same, as is the remedy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first class `total` is a function as well as an attribute of the class. That is not okay :) Python thinks that the total you are referring to in the final line is the integer variable total and not the function.

It is considered a good practice to name the function `total` as `get_total` instead

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have a property called total, as well as a function called `total`. When you run `roll`, you are overwriting the class's definition of `total`.

In other words, before you run `roll`, `player1.total` is a function. However, once you run roll, you set `player1.total` to be a number. From then on, when you reference `player1.total`, you are referring to that number.

You might want to rename the `total` function to something like `getTotal`, or something similar.