# Getting error: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python

The error text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 38, in <module>
    new_restaurant.number_served()
```

Where is a problem?

```py
class Restaurant:
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
        self.number_served = 0


    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print(f"\nRestaurant name: {self.restaurant_name}.")
        print(f"Cuisine type: {self.cuisine_type}")

    def open_restaurant(self):
        print(f"Restaurant {self.restaurant_name} status: open!")


    def closed_restaurant(self):
        print(f"Restaurant {self.restaurant_name} status: closed!")


    def set_number_served(self, number):
        self.number_served = number


    def incriment_number_served(self, number):
        self.number_served += number


new_restaurant = Restaurant("...", "...")

new_restaurant.set_number_served(50)
new_restaurant.number_served()
```

Comment: Use backticks instead of single quotes for code blocks; fixed it for you.

Comment: `new_restaurant.number_served` is an integer, not a function. Don't add the brackets if you want to access it

Comment: from initial impression, it looks like you are trying to use number_served similar to how you would with a programming language like java? i.e. you don't need to define a getter/setter here unless its needed. have you tried `new_rest.number_served += 50`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - TypeError: 'int' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121119/python-typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `new_restaurant.number_served()`, exactly what do you expect this to mean? In particular: where does `new_restaurant.number_served` come from? Therefore, is that something that can be called with `()`, or just an integer? Therefore, should we write `()` after it? In your own words, what do you think the `()` are for? (BTW: it's spelled "increment".)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. The error message says exactly what the problem is and where it occurred, so what are you confused about exactly? As far as I can tell, you just added the parentheses by mistake. See [ask] for tips like making a [mre] to avoid basic mistakes like that in the future.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs that question isn't a good duplicate because the *cause* of the `TypeError` there is entirely different. I wrote a canonical for general "how do I debug a TypeError?" questions, because without a more specific analysis (i.e. "I determined that the TypeError happens here with this MRE; I think it should not happen because [reasoning]; what do I misunderstand?"), that's normally what's called for. As this is not a help desk/debugging service, I would rather teach fishing than hand out fish.

Comment: (In this case, the problem is what I would normally consider a typo, but it's more useful to show how to pin down the typo than to just close as not reproducible.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you for writing that canonical, hopefully it goes better than the other ones :) That being said, although this question is answered in your canonical, it is not in the most evident spot. Quickly scrolling through, as most people will, I find the heading, "If something 'is not callable'" - I would expect to find the answer here, but I don't. Instead, it is found in "Code like 1('test') doesn't make sense because 1 isn't a function (or a type)."

Comment: Because the diagnosis requires actual debugging, I can't expect it to get to the right spot every time. I'm planning to split up the answer into a couple of different sections, and try to show an object example of the "try to analyze the error message" part in more detail (and give that more focus). But the point is well taken that the specific advice sections should repeat the more obvious/natural causes.

Answer (score 1):

I personally feel you are slightly over-thinking the `number_served` attribute access.

Here's another way you could approach this, without using helper methods to set/increment the `number_served` attribute:

```py
class Restaurant:

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
        self.number_served = 0


new_restaurant = Restaurant("...", "...")

new_restaurant.number_served = 50
new_restaurant.number_served += 2

print(new_restaurant.number_served)  # 52
```

One can also use [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) for better type hinting and IDE support:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Restaurant:
    restaurant_name: str
    cuisine_type: str
    number_served: int = 0

...  # rest is the same
```